# PDF's, embedded files get stripped away

Tags: windows, pdf, embedded

We download some PDF's from a webapp. This PDF's contains a XML file embedded. On some Windows client machines this embedded files get stripped away and we cannot find any program o specific process that is doing this.

Is there any known browser plug-in, antivirus or PDF plugin that may interfere in this way ?

Comment: What browsers/plugins or other software are you using in this process? What Windows version? What PDF Viewer? What evidence do you have that the contents are being stripped? How are the PDFs created? Which Webapp?

Comment: The PDF is created and saved on the server and delivered on request. The PDF on server is complete, with embedded file. Most clients have no problems. Diferent Windows versions V/7/10. It really does not happen here but on other sites...

Comment: Please add this and any subsequent information to the original post using the EDIT button. Please clarify what you mean by "It... does not happen here but on other sites".